# Turn Markdown "code" blocks into plain "preformatted" blocks on Super User

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor

On SU, can we remove the default syntax highlighting?  It seems that most uses for the Markdown 4-space-indent-code-block on SU are not actual code, and the syntax highlighting is more of a hindrance than a help.

I think what SU really needs isn't a *code block*, but a *preformatted block*, and I think the user-friendliest implemementation would simply change the 4-space-indent Markdown to render as `<pre></pre>` instead of `<pre><code></code></pre>`.

---

Here's [one awful example](https://superuser.com/questions/114161/win7-bluescreen-irq-not-less-or-equal-athrxusb-sys) (see the [first revision](https://superuser.com/posts/114161/revisions)).  The syntax highlighting was useless to the final rendering of the post, and it made the post hideously slow to load.

Comment: Brilliant. It would save all the peculiar syntax highlighting one gets when printing a routing table or a configuration file.

Comment: Also, on the *off* chance someone does *legitimately* want color-coding (maybe editing an XML configuration file or something), that person will probably be technical enough to type `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` him- or herself.

Comment: There's routing tables on superuser??

Comment: @Sam_Cogan: yeah, there are.  ServerFault doesn't *want* home-networking questions.

Comment: Still some highlighting I'd like: a fat red underline when the space between Super and User or Stack and Flow or Server and Fault is missing ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: maybe when they *show a space in the site logos* i'll start remembering that the names of these sites contain spaces.  until then, you should totally write a greasemonkey script for that. :)

Comment: @~quack, here's a bookmarklet for you instead ;-) http://jsbin.com/awina/

Comment: @Arjan: +1 for hilarity.  but i meant a script to do what you said: the fat red underline when the space is missing.  :)

Comment: Of course, I know you meant. Unless you know of a way to force everyone to use such script, I guess editing is actually easier. Too bad I cannot edit at Meta ;-)

Comment: hmmm. fair point. in that case could you modify the other trilogy logos too?

Comment: The name of the site is in the title bar, logos often mash words together as one.

Comment: +! this is a great idea!

Comment: I believe this should apply to server fault as well.  I frequently want to post pre-formated text, that isn't source code there.  I think the need for highlighted source code is pretty rare.

Comment: If you need to dump points, you need to bounty up old questions.

Comment: @random: don't think i'm not considering it.  but should i really be dumping points into *Jeff* of all people??

Comment: Since Pollyanna is going around trying to rid his points, you should send them back.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, we probably don't need syntax highlighting on Super User -- it can now be disabled on a per-site basis.

(The prettify JavaScript is still served; that'd be a much deeper change.)

Comment: From my initial testing, using user0x36E0's suggestion from the comments will not work to get the syntax highlighting if we need it?  Is there any way to get it?