# Why isn't shell syntax highlighting working?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've been all over Meta Stack Overflow and the help pages, and frankly I'm just tired of looking now. I've tried `<!-- language: shell -->` and `<!-- language: sh -->`, but I can't seem to get POSIX-shell syntax highlighting [on this answer](https://superuser.com/a/647196/144700). I've just given up on trying to highlight the AppleScript; there's a tag for it but nothing mentions that it's supported.

Comment: It's been disabled for quite some time. Here's a feature-request to have it enabled: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4266

Comment: @slhck Was it ever enabled?

Comment: @slhck Oh, okay. You can write up a quick answer if you want, btw.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, [until March 2010](http://meta.superuser.com/a/840/48078), it seems. What quack says in the question makes me believe it was turned on by default.